# How to delete from javascript array an ajax when it is done

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, variables

How how do I delete a jQuery Deferred from an array when it finishes?  I have:

```
myarray[key]=$.ajax({

}).done(function(response){

 // work with response,
 // then delete myarray[key];

});
```

This does not work:

```
var myvar=function(){
  if(myvar){
    alert(1);
  }
}
```

Seems like the declaration has to finish for an event of checking whether the variable is set or not, so delete of the variable inside the variable declaration shouldn't work How to, with a timeout?

Comment: Why not just `delete myarray[key]` ? Your problem isn't clear. Can you post more code so that we don't have to shoot in the dark (many possible problems here) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether or not myarray is an Array or an Object.  If it's an Object, you could just do

```
delete myarray[key];
```

But if it's an Array, then it's a little more complicated.  John Resig wrote post about Array element removal [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/)

If you want to do it more simply, and it's an Array, you could remove it with

```
myarray[key] = undefined;
```

But you should note that `myarray` doesn't get any smaller when you do this.

`$.ajax` returns a Deferred object, and `.done()` returns a different Deferred object.  Optimally, you'd do the following:

```
myarray[key]=$.ajax({

});
myarray[key].done(function(response){
 // work with response,
 // then delete myarray[key];
});
```

Comment: Will the code get properly executed at an ajax .done inside the very same array key being declared? my assumption it won't work has to do with what I posted as not working in the question.